# Form validation rule does not render custom message

Tags: yii2, active-form, form-verification

I am using Yii2 ActiveForm to make a default templated registration form. In the form the user must specify a signup key in order to complete the registration. The signup key must have a length between 6 and 10 characters.

I have deleted all other validation rules for my form except the one I am having trouble with. The rule is being applied, but is rendering a default form validation message.

Here is the rule in question:

```php
[ 
    'betaKey',
    'string',
    'length' => [6, 10],
    'message' => 'Signup Codes are between 6 and 10 characters.' 
]
```

The above rule is being applied, I know this because when I change the length to `[2, 10]` the rule is no longer triggered. I have read the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html), though please feel free to let me know if I have missed something.

Here is the javascript being rendered by Yii:

```php
yii.validation.string(value, messages, {
    "message": "Signup Codes are between 6 and 10 characters.",
    "min": 2,
    "tooShort": "Beta Key should contain at least 2 characters.",
    "max": 10,
    "tooLong": "Beta Key should contain at most 10 characters.",
    "skipOnEmpty": 1
});
```

`message` is never rendered by the validator. All other core-validators in Yii2 use `message` for specifying a custom error message. Why is that not the case here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation does not say anything about the two characteristics, "tooShort" and "tooLong". I was able to set these explicitly and the form works as intended now. I wonder if this is expected functionality by the developers as "message" is still a valid input. At any rate I hope this helps anyone else having similar issues.

```
        [ 
            'betaKey',
            'string',
            'length' => [2, 10],
            'tooShort' => "Test-Short",
            'tooLong' => "Test-Long"
        ]
```

Comment: Remember downvotes on answers cost reputation. If you are going to use it, you should have a good reason.

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted. I upvoted it to counteract. It is a valid answer and more to the points something that works but it is not documented.